# How to set Enterprise Mode in IE 11 Using HTML or Java

Tags: java, html, internet-explorer-11

I want to set compatibility mode in IE, Now I have been using *X-UA-Compatible*. But I came across a technique called **Enterprise Mode**, in which our page will render in best possible way.

I want to know how to set Enterprise mode using *HTML tags* or *Java's response header*.

Answer (score 5):

**I want to know how to set Enterprise mode using HTML tags or Java's response header.**

You can't do this.

---

Source [How to Enable and Use Internet Explorer 11′s Enterprise Mode](http://www.howtogeek.com/184634/how-to-enable-and-use-internet-explorer-11s-enterprise-mode/?PageSpeed=noscript)

**How It Works**

> Internet Explorer’s Enterprise Mode is a special compatibility mode in Internet Explorer 11. A website that loads in Enterprise Mode renders like it did in Internet Explore 8. Some businesses have standardized on older versions of Internet Explorer and may use internal web applications that just don’t function with modern versions of Internet Explorer. Rather than stick with Internet Explorer 8 on Windows XP, which is reaching the end of its long life, Microsoft wants to encourage these businesses to upgrade to a modern version of Windows and Internet Explorer.
>
> **Websites can’t ask to be rendered in this mode**, and it won’t appear in the normal menus as an option for typical users. Microsoft wants businesses to provide their own list of websites that will be automatically loaded in Enterprise Mode. It’s also available as a menu option that can be toggled on and off, but this menu option is hidden by default and must be enabled in the group policy editor.

See [Turn on Enterprise Mode and use a site list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn640699.aspx) for more information.